# HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type in Jetty server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I have de following endpoint

```
@Path("endpoint")
public class MyEndPoint {

@POST
@Path("{paramA}/{paramB}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void trackPOST(@PathParam("paramA") String paramA, @PathParam("paramB") String paramB,
                      @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
                      @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                      @RequestBody Model data,
                      @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
}
```

and I am doing a post request to the path `/endpoint/paramAValue/paramBValue`

with a Json Body that matches the `Model` class (only a `String` property with a setter and a getter)

and with the header `Content-Type: application/json;`

and I get the following error from my Rest client

```
{
  "code": 415,
  "error": "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Try removing the `;` after `application/json`

Comment: try adding Accept: application/json to your Header, also check if you are pointing to the right API.

Comment: Firstly, `@RequestBody` is a Spring MVC annotation and doesn't work with JAX-RS/Jersey, which is the actual framework you are using (_on top of_ Spring Boot). Second, do you have a JSON provider (e.g. `jersey-media-json-jackson`)?

Comment: I ve tried also remoing @RequestBody from the parameter. I have the following dependnencies on my pom: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.{ackson-core, jackson-annotations, jackson-databind}

Comment: Well I now replaced it by jackson-bom dependencies. I can see that if I try to receive an string instead an object in the method signatura, and I put application/json on the client requests, it is going OK and receiving the string, so the JSON to object mapping is what is failing